# Hitting the back button after a batch process cause a nasty error

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I have a batch process (using batch API) that runs when a user on my site tries to launch a non signed Java applet. The batch process does all the needed codesigning and other things and then redirects the user to the applet when it is finished. This all works well but if the user hits back from the applet page they get this nasty error with the text from my batch_error function.

[image]

It seems that this occurs because when you hit back you end up trying to run a batch process that no longer exists. Is there anyway to avoid this?

EDIT:

Here is my function that sets up the batch process:

```
function batch_codesign($node) {
$batch = array(
   'operations' => array(
        array('batch_codesign_process', array("create_jar_files", $node)),
        array('batch_codesign_process', array("output_new_agentsheets_applet_html", $node)),
    ),
    'finished' => 'batch_codesign_finished',
    'title' => t('Codesigning'),
    'init_message' => t('Codesigning ' . $node->title .'.'),
    'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total.'),
    'error_message' => t('An error has occured while condesigning the project, please try again.'),    
    );
batch_set($batch);
$nid = $node->nid;
batch_process("path/to/endpoint");
}
```

Comment: Can you not do the codesigning and other things beforehand or is the applet being uploaded right then?

Comment: Its a somewhat strange use case where we sometimes have 100s of people uploading projects (which contain applets) at the same time but only some small percentage of those projects will be played right away. If we do the codesining with every upload it can cause performance issues and sometimes interfere with uploads because the codesinging takes much longer then the upload. The codesigning is a long process because the applets come from a legacy applicaiton which does not generate the applet in the correct format. We need to jump though many hoops to get the correct manfiest and such.

Comment: can you not disable their back button on that page via inserting inline js? I know disabling the back button is bad web-fu, but can be ok in some extreme cases, especially if you include a note.

Comment: This is a very worthwhile question, as this even occurs for admins doing updates and such if they accidentally use the back button.

Comment: @DrCord Oh I didn't know that was possible and I'm sure that wouldn't work on all browser, but I think I would prefer to find a solution that didn't involve hacking the back button ;)

Comment: Could you use an AJAX overlay instead of a new page to process the batch?  Then when the user hits back they wouldn't go back to the start of the batch, they'd go back to the page before the one in which they uploaded their applet...?

Comment: @Darvanen that sounds like a great idea but I wonder how this could be done? Doesn't batch_process automatically run in a new window? Is there someway to configure this?

Comment: What about onpopstate javascript method?  It basically allows you to add your own customization during a back/forward process.  not sure if this would break the default functionality.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

Comment: @Mike2012 I'm afraid the 'how' of that idea is beyond me at the moment.

Comment: Still no answers and the bounty is running out :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution, however you'll need to alter the menu callback for `batch` and wrap the default page callback.

Create your hook_menu_alter() and change `batch` to be your own page callback function, and update the file attribute (unset if in your .module)

```
// Default page for batch operations.
$items['batch'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'system_batch_page',
  'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
);
```

Basically your callback can call the default `system_batch_page()` page callback (wrap it). From there you can adjust what happens when someone hits an inactive or stale batch.